# Homophone Challenge

Tags: word, english, language

There are three words that sound the same
But each has a different name

One of the earliest words spoken by a baby, usually repeated twice.
A part of speech hard to classify, sometimes used to show position
And the foundation of the modern economy, as a verb

Can you find the homophones?

Comment: It's a preposition.

Comment: It ain't no lie, baby...      :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The words are:

One of the earliest words spoken by a baby, usually repeated twice.

> **bye**

A part of speech hard to classify, sometimes used to show position

> **by**

And the foundation of the modern economy, as a verb

> **buy**